# Python split single tuple value into multiple values

Tags: python

I have the following tuple value and wanted to split single tuple value into multiple values.I tried converting the tuple to string and used split(),splitlines() based on \n as delimiter however it didn't work.Any inputs please?

```
INPUT:
('2018-10-23\n2018-10-25\n2018-10-26\n2018-10-27\n2018-10-28\n2018-10-30\n', 0)

OUTPUT:
2018-10-23
2018-10-25
2018-10-27
2018-10-28
2018-10-30
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], what exactly do you mean by *"didn't work"*?

Comment: Is the output supposed to be a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the first element of the tuple:

```
inpt = ('2018-10-23\n2018-10-25\n2018-10-26\n2018-10-27\n2018-10-28\n2018-10-30\n', 0)

result = inpt[0].strip().split()

for e in result:
    print(e)
```

**Output**

```
2018-10-23
2018-10-25
2018-10-26
2018-10-27
2018-10-28
2018-10-30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list, you can use `str.splitlines`. If you want the output you posted on the screen... just print it.

```
>>> inp = ('2018-10-23\n2018-10-25\n2018-10-26\n2018-10-27\n2018-10-28\n2018-10-30\n', 0)
>>> 
>>> inp[0].splitlines()
['2018-10-23',
 '2018-10-25',
 '2018-10-26',
 '2018-10-27',
 '2018-10-28',
 '2018-10-30']
>>> 
>>> print(inp[0], end='')
2018-10-23
2018-10-25
2018-10-26
2018-10-27
2018-10-28
2018-10-30
```